# If instance respondsToSelector - why still "unrecognized selector sent to instance"?

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime, respondstoselector

Right, I'm officially confused.

This is called in a `NSTableView` subclass on 10.8 and as we can learn from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the headers `NSTableView` implements `NSDraggingSource` so all should be good:

```
 if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(draggingSession:movedToPoint:)])
    [super draggingSession:session movedToPoint:screenPoint];
```

When the containing method (override of [`draggingSession:movedToPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSDraggingSource/draggingSession%3amovedToPoint%3a) in the subclass) is called, the second line however throws the beloved '**unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1054092c0**' exception.

Could anybody **please** explain what is going on here?!

Comment: Set a an exception breakpoint and check the class of the instance (0x1054092c0') in your example. - Note also that `[super respondsToSelector:sel]` is *identical* to `[self.respondsToSelector:sel]` (it just calls the super-implementation of `respondsToSelector:`, which you probably did *not* override, but still checks for the selector in `self`).

Comment: Show the full exception message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `[super respondsToSelector:@selector(draggingSession:movedToPoint:)]` is the same as `[self respondsToSelector:@selector(draggingSession:movedToPoint:)]`. `super` allows you to invoke the superclass implementation of the given method; in this case, `respondsToSelector:`. But if your class (or whatever class this object is) does not override `-respondsToSelector:` (99.9% of classes will not need to override `-respondsToSelector:`), then the superclass implementation is the same as the implementation of the class of `self`. Basically, in both cases, you are checking to see if the current object (`self`) responds to the selector.

So, what you're seeing is this: `self` responds to the selector, but the superclass of the class this is in does not have an implementation for the selector. What does that mean? Either the current class, or somewhere between the current class as the class of `self`, this method is implemented. That's why `self` responds to it. But there is no superclass implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is actually:

```
if ([[NSTableView class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(draggingSession:movedToPoint:)])
    [super draggingSession:session movedToPoint:screenPoint];
```

As pointed out by newacct, `super` refers to the superclass of the class in which the method is implemented, whereas `[self superclass]` is the superclass of the instance on which it is called, which could be a subclass of your custom class (a grandchild of `NSTableView`). Of course, it is unlikely you would create such a sub-subclass, but you might as well do things right, and this code is anyway clearer in its intent.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the hints -
this does indeed work fine:

```
 if ([[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(draggingSession:movedToPoint:)])
    [super draggingSession:session movedToPoint:screenPoint];
```

Comment: This is wrong. `[self superclass]` is not necessarily the superclass of the class this code is in. It is only if `self`'s class is the class this code is in. If `self`'s class is a subclass of this class, then `[self superclass]` is either this class or some subclass thereof, and therefore checking whether `[self superclass]`'s instances respond is not enough.

Comment: Read through the question - this code is obviously called from the same subclass `super` is called in the example given at the beginning so this code is perfectly valid for the scenario posted and solves the issue

Comment: You are misreading what I am saying. Let's say this code is in class `Foo`, okay? And the superclass of `Foo` is `Bar`, okay? `[self superclass]` is not necessarily `Bar`, because `[self class]` is not necessarily `Foo`.

Comment: newacct is right: the class of `super` is not necessarily `[self superclass]`. The class of `super` is NSTableView, but if your custom subclass has a subclass, then `self` is a grandchild of NSTableView, so [self superclass] is just the child class, which does implement the selector. The correct check could simply be `[[NSTableView class] instancesRespondToSelector:...`